# Creating a grid of polar histograms (python)

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I wish to create a sub plot that looks like the following picture,
it is supposed to contain 25 polar histograms, and I wish to add them to the plot one by one.
needs to be in python.
I already figured I need to use matplotlib but can't seem to figure it out completely.

[image]

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a grid of polar axes via `projection='polar'`.

`hist` creates a histogram, also when working with polar axes. Note that the x is in radians with a range of 2π. It works best when you give the bins explicitly as a `linspace` from 0 to 2π (or from -π to π, depending on the data). The third parameter of `linspace` should be one more than the number of bars that you'd want for the full circle.

About the exact parameters of `axs[i][j].hist(x, bins=np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, np.random.randint(7, 30), endpoint=True), color='dodgerblue', ec='black')`:

- `axs[i][j]` draw on the `j`th subplot of the `i`th line
- `.hist` create a histogram
- `x`: the values that are put into bins
- `bins=`: to enter the bins (either a fixed number between lowest and highest `x` or some explicit boundaries; default is 10 fixed boundaries)
- `np.random.randint(7, 30)` a random whole number between 7 and 29
- `np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n, endpoint=True)` divide the range between 0 and 2π into `n` equal parts; `endpoint=True` makes boundaries at 0, at 2π and at `n-2` positions in between; when `endpoint=False` there will be a boundary at 0, at `n-1` positions in between but none at the end
- `color='dodgerblue'`: the color of the histogram bars will be blueish
- `ec='black'`: the *edge color* of the bars will be black

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(8, 8),
                        subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        x = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, 50)
        axs[i][j].hist(x, bins=np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, np.random.randint(7, 30)), color='dodgerblue', ec='black')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: grid of polar histograms]

Comment: thank you very much! this is very helpful! can you please explain the parameters in the axs[i][j] line? I am not sure I understand them. thank you again!